# How to get an NUnit test project to use a custom exception filter?

Tags: c#, nunit, asp.net-web-api

I have an NUnit test project that runs tests against a Web API project.  When there was an unhandled exception on the server side, I would just get an opaque HTTP 500 error, which was very little use for debugging.  So I googled the issue, and found [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/handling-exceptions-in-asp.net-web-api.htm), which helped me create a nice little custom exception filter, and now I can pass the server side exception details to the UI in the response.

The article explains how to get this filter to work globally, by adding a line to `Application_Start`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new MyExceptionFilter());
```

Unfortunately, this line never gets executed when I run my unit tests.

The filter works great when I decorate my controller methods with `[MyExceptionFilter]`, but I *really* don't want to have to go pasting this decorator on every single controller in my API.

Is there some way to get the NUnit project to apply this custom exception filter globally?

Answer (score 1):

When you do a unit test you are executing classes and nothing else. In the case of a Web application that runs on a Web server, apart from the classes you have a lot of other elements (Cookies, Requests, Responses, Sessions, etc). In your Application_Start when you register a filter, you are telling to the Web server to handle unhandled exceptions. This means that the server itself is responsible of this handling.

In your unit test you never have the context of the Web application, because you're testing classes and methods. It's a bad idea to expect a behaviour of this kind when you only need to test the atomicity of the code.

For example, a good unit test might be (based on the article):

- If something occurs, expect a business Exception, like CustomerNotFoundException

If the test triggers the expected exception, then the test is OK. Then you can execute a filter for the unhandled exception, but it's completely outside of the test boundaries.

As far as I know, it's possible to mock certain parts of the Web application (for example to emulate cookies in a fake HttpContext, there is a lot of responses here in StackOverflow). It's always desired to avoid this, because you need to decouple your tests from external behaviours, and certainly to mock the entire Web process is much more complicated and less beneficial.

Consider the business exception: to throw what you expect to throw, based on your logic. If it's not possible to handle all the conditions, attach a filter in Application_Start, but it's completely outside of your methods in the controller.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation.  I'm not looking to handle specific exceptions; I'm looking for the general catch case when a unit test breaks and I don't know why, e.g. someone checked in code that messed up something on the server side, and now all I know is that my unit tests are throwing HTTP 500 errors.  I need to be able to debug those unit tests to see what went wrong.